# How to use flash game engine?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have learn AS3 for sometime and I really want to continue develop it in social game flatform. However, I have never used any engine before and I am really confused about what is everything I download from those( a bunch of AS file T_T). Since I learn flash and as3 by myself so it's hard for me to figure out everything by myself.

Could anyone teach me how to use those? Is there any tutorial out there about this area?

Comment: Has anyone ever accused you of being to vague?

Comment: Hi @Brian Lin. Welcome to SO, read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), [rest of generic newbie greeting], etc.
Now that that's out of the way, you need to know: you get what you pay for. Questions on SO are an investment of your time. If you haven't invested any of your time to write a decent, grammatically correct, thought-out, on-topic question, we community members of SO feel less obligated to invest *our* time to help you. There aren't short-cuts in programming, and game design **is** programming. I just don't want you to be deluded into thinking you'll be the next Notch or anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of good tutorials on social game development on the web. One of the best sites is http://www.emanueleferonato.com/, there you may find lots of tutorials and code samples on game development, game/physics/3d engines tests and comparisons. 
Start with this [article](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2009/11/04/creating-a-flash-facebook-application-with-the-facebook-actionscript-api/).